# Изменение размера окна на дисплеях с разным разрешением PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

Если задать принудительно размер виджета в PyQt, то на разных дисплеях, с разным разрешением, окно приложения выглядит по-разному (также различен физический размер пикселей). Нужно добиться более-менне одинакового вида окна приложения на разных экранах. Как можно сделать это изящнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

только если xrandr дёргать, чтобы исправить настройки dpi.

если речь идет о работе одного окна на двух разных дисплеях одновременно (а не двух разных окон одной программы, каждое на своём дисплее), то элегантно не получится, только если патчить кутишый рендерер виджетов, чтобы можно было задать разное dpi для разных областей окна или какая-нибудь такая наркомания

если тебе нужно менять именно размер самого окна (а не масштаб виджетов в нём), то это будут какие-то еще более дикие хаки, потому что тебе нужно будет окно неквадратной формы.

так что самое оптимальное -- написать в README как пользователю исправить значение dpi чтобы приложение отображалось одинаково